# How to get SMS message code to be copy to input fields directly in Angular17

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material

This code was changed after first answer. I tried this, but angular give me some errors.  How can i fix them?

TS:

```
async otpRequest() {
    if ('OTPCredential' in window) {

      const abortController = new AbortController()
      let timer = setTimeout(() => {
        abortController.abort()
      }, 10 * 1000);

      let o: CredentialRequestOptions = {
        otp: { transport: ['sms'] },
        signal: abortController.signal
      }
    
      let content = await window.navigator['credentials'].get(o)
      const otpCtrl = this.frm.get('codeField')
      if (otpCtrl) {
        //'code' does not exist 
        otpCtrl.patchValue(content!.code);
      }
    }
  }
```

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field class="codeField" #matFormCode>
    <mat-label> SMS-Code </mat-label>
    <span matPrefix> &nbsp;</span>
    <input type="text" matInput formControlName=`enter code here`"codeField"  id='code' #codeInput autocomplete="one-time-code" inputmode="numeric"/>
</mat-form-field>
```

Log of errors:

```
       X [ERROR] TS2322: Type '{ otp: { transport: string[]; }; signal: AbortSignal; }' is not assignable to type 'CredentialRequestOptions'.    
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'otp' does not exist in type 'CredentialRequestOptions'. [plugin angular-compiler]

    src/app/login/login.component.ts:46:8:
      46 │         otp: { transport: ['sms'] },
         ╵         ~~~


X [ERROR] TS2339: Property 'code' does not exist on type 'Credential'. [plugin angular-compiler]

    src/app/login/login.component.ts:53:36:
      53 │         otpCtrl.patchValue(content!.code);
         ╵                                     ~~~~
```

I tried to add this on stacblitz: [my code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-caerud?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fapp%2Flogin%2Flogin.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Flogin%2Flogin.component.html,src%2Findex.html,src%2Fmain.ts&template=node&title=Angular%20Starter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `patchValue` you can add the code below!

[Docs for OTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OTPCredential)

```
async otpRequest() {
    if ('OTPCredential' in window) {

      const abortController = new AbortController()
      let timer = setTimeout(() => {
        abortController.abort()
      }, 10 * 1000);

      let o: CredentialRequestOptions = {
        otp: { transport: ['sms'] },
        signal: abortController
      }

      const content = await window.navigator['credentials'].get(o);

      //do what ever you want to do with the received code, probably send it to server
     // assuming `form` here is your formGroup. First we get the code field
     // using the 'get' method
     const otpCtrl = this.form.get('codeField');
     // check if the field exists then apply the value on the control
     if(otpCtrl) {
          // patchValue will apply the new value replacing the old value!
          // assuming contents here is your OTP
          otpCtrl.patchValue(content.code);
     }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I tried this code and have some errors:
1) Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'signal', 'otp' dont exist in type 'CredentialRequestOptions'.  in:
let o: CredentialRequestOptions = {
        otp: { transport: ['sms'] },
        signal: abortController.signal
      }
2) Type 'CredentialRequestOptions' has no properties in common with type 'CredentialRequestOptions'. in:
      const content = await window.navigator['credentials'].get(o);

Comment: And, Property 'code' does not exist on type 'Credential'. in:
        otpCtrl.patchValue(content.code);

Comment: @Ermak the return type seems to wrong can you try any type or OTPCredential type instead?

Comment: Maybe, i need add some import or change some options?

Comment: Type OTPCreditails dosent exist in my project. Thats im add 

interface CredentialRequestOptions {
  otp: OTPOptions
  signal: any
}

interface OTPOptions {
  transport: string[]
}

Comment: @Ermak just give any type and get rid of the error, then console.log the output of content, check if OTP property exists inside it

Comment: I will change my question and add errors log

Comment: @Ermak can you try this code `let o: any  = {
        otp: { transport: ['sms'] },
        signal: abortController.signal
      }
    
      let content: any = await window.navigator['credentials'].get(o)`

Comment: I have tried this code. I tried this code and, there are no mistakes, but autocomplete SMS-Code doesnt work

Comment: @Ermak atleast could you share the output of `content`, also plz share a stackblitz where the issue happens for debugging!

Comment: i added a link to stackblitz

Comment: @Ermak could you share the output of `content` property in your code, you can change the data in the datastucture but share the output of that

Comment: Changing done. App dont see the let content = await...